# Why does everyone in Game Of Thrones have a British accent?

Tags: game-of-thrones, languages, accent

### What is the reason for the British accents in Game Of Thrones?

Specifically in the North and South, not in what is considered foreign lands like Qarth and Meereen.
Although George R. R. Martin is American and the show is directed towards American audiences, everyone in Game of Thrones speaks in some sort of British accent.

Going through some of the characters with accents:

- Ned Stark has a northern accent (actually Sheffield).
- Robb Stark has a northern accent (actually Scottish).
- Jon Snow and Theon Greyjoy are non-northern actors with northern accents.
- Arya Stark has a slight West Country accent.
- Catelyn Stark speaks with a slight southern English accent.
- King Robert Baratheon has a northern accent.
- Some of the knights in the Vale speak with Welsh accents
- Jorah Mormont has a Northern accent (actually Scottish in real life)
- Davos Seaworth has a Northern accent (actually Irish)
- Tyrion Lannister umm, [not the best accent](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/entertainment/news/article.cfm?c_id=1501119&objectid=10812416).

Anyway, you get the point that the English accent is the theme here.
Obviously there are many more characters that speak with British accents, so what was the reason for the British accent?

Comment: Shouldn't the Question then be "Why did they choose to film the show in UK with an overwhelming British cast"? As it is now it seems kinda absurd, no offense. As you note yourself in examples, If there are Britons in the cast, how else are they going to speak? Like the French?

Comment: Duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59521/2256

Comment: @TLP, how on earth is that question a duplicate of the one you linked? The question is　`Why are most of the main characters Caucasian in Game Of Thrones?` What part of that question deals with dialects?

Comment: @KyloRen Because an ***answer** in that duplicate question* answers it (at least the core reason: Based on Medieval Europe (especially Britain and the War of the Roses [+Drgaons & Ice-Zombies]). There has been numerous discussions on meta about whether that is a good thing or not, such as these (randomly picked ones): http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9743/30726 or http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9743/30726 and many others ... Argueably, since yours is voted higher, the other (older) one could also be closed...

Comment: @BMWurm,the issue I am seeing here is that question does not relate to this question at all.Yes it has an answer that could also be used as an answer here as well,but when looking for the reason as to why English dialect is used,you will never find that question in a search,this search brings up this question,does not even mention accent, https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=why+is+game+of+thrones+set+in+english&oq=why+is+game+of+thrones+set+in+english&aqs=chrome..69i57.75450j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=why+does+game+of+thrones+use+british+actors ,put `accents` in the search is higher still.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41722/discussion-on-question-by-kyloren-why-does-everyone-in-game-of-thrones-have-a-br).

Comment: If the war technology pre-dates gunpowder, all must speak with British accents.  See Gladiator, Rome, LotR, etc.

This is known.

Comment: @Aegon: “If there are Britons in the cast, how else are they going to speak?” — They’re British *actors*, dear boy. They’ll speak [however](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_House) [they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_McNulty) [damn](http://reservoirdogs.wikia.com/wiki/Mr_Orange) [well](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/James_Gordon_(Gary_Oldman)) [fancy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BASELWRpRks).

Comment: And, just because no-one’s mentioned it, for the record, Petyr Baelish speaks with an accent unlike anything heard in Britain.

Comment: Oh — Jaime Lannister also doesn’t sound particularly British. Something Scandinavian, I would guess.

Comment: Just to clarify. What is deemed American English is a misnomer. It is a dialect. An analogy would be that English, as spoken in England, is the tree, all other, as spoken abroad are branches.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/115811)

Comment: I suppose that's why Shrek had such a strange fake Scottish accent

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - if a single actor is trying to fit with a mainly American cast to fit into a programme set in the real life place of America, then yeah it's a good idea for them to put on an American accent. But it would be bizarre to have the entire cast arbitrarily change their accent to another one for no apparent reason...

Comment: @colmde: sure. I'm just saying British actors can do accents.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### David Benioff & DB Weiss thought that the show suited dialog with English, Scottish and Irish accents.

Even though Game Of Thrones is written by an American author and is intended for American audiences, the show specifically uses British accented dialog.
As many people know, Game of Thrones is filmed in Belfast and the majority of on-location shooting occurs in Northern Ireland as is the case with Castle Black which is set in an abandoned quarry a few minutes drive north of Belfast. Several of the more exotic locations are filmed elsewhere, but most is in Northern Ireland.

But, speaking as to why the acting was to be done in British accents, an interview David Benioff & DB Weiss. They go on to say that Northern Ireland was the feel they were looking for show but, it was the fact that they had always had  in their minds that they would use British accents. The [location](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Filming_locations) also played a part as that was the general feel they were going for, old English history type feel.

Taken from the interview below,

> *"And for whatever reason in our minds, we had always heard, English
>   accents, English, Scottish, Irish accents. I think having this dialog
>   being spoken by someone with a kind of Malibu surfer, it would not
>   have seemed right."*

[HBO’s ‘Game of Thrones’: Further Proof That America Loves British Accents](http://dailylounge.com/the-daily/entry/hbos-game-of-thrones-further-proof-that-america-loves-british-accents)

> "It's such an ingrained part of fantasy and science fiction that I'm a
>   little surprised when those kind of characters don't speak in British
>   accents," Matt Zoller Seitz, the TV critic for New York magazine told
>   BBC News. "In the fantasy realm they could have any kind of accent but
>   British does seem to be the default."

Comment: Was there a single Scottish accent in the show? I know there are several Scottish actors who switch to an English accent. When I was reading the books I imaged the Wildlings with a Scottish / Scandinadian sound, but as it is, I can't think of anyone sounding Scottish.

Comment: @MikeyMouse, Richard Madden and Iain Glen are Scottish.

Comment: I know, and a bunch of others, but they all switch to english accents for the show. I heard Ygritte gets annoyed when people ask her to say "You know nothing Jon Snow" when she says it in her own accent, and they want her to say it with the same accent she put on in the show

Comment: I would note that even though GRRM is American, Westeros is modeled after England. The [map of Westeros](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Known_World) is an exact mirror image of [the map of England](http://www.mapsofworld.com/united-kingdom/). It might have influenced this choice.

Comment: @MatthieuM, of further note (and corroborating evidence supportingthe use of British accents) is that the series (or at least the beginning of it) [was directly inspired by the English Wars of the Roses](https://youtu.be/VjO55pKuBo4): I mean, Stark->York, Lannister->Lancaster... can it get more obvious?

Comment: @errantlinguist: Not being familiar with England/Scotland's history, I'll just nod along :D At a superficial level, at least the Lannister<-Lancaster sounds similar ^^

Comment: @KyloRen, those actors are indeed Scottish but AFAIK they are speaking English without much "Scottishness"... for example, [Rose Leslie](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Rose_Leslie) is from Aberdeen but (assuming she can speak Scottish English at all) her accent in the show seems more from Yorkshire than from Scotland, and most definitely does *not* have any [Doric Scots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doric_dialect_(Scotland)) influence as it might have.

Comment: @errantlinguist, absolutely agree with you there.

Comment: I think the reason people expect people in fantasy movies to speak with British accents is because it tends to take place in pre-technological, medieval worlds, either explicitly a long time ago or at least similar to our world a long time ago. American accents are simply too recent and would sound out of place in such a world. They are associated with the modern world and present day America. - In addition, for Americans, it's probably simply to make it sound other-worldly.

Comment: From the interview quote, I wonder if the Malibu surfer was a light dig at Kevin Costner's performance as Robin Hood in "Prince of Thieves" :)

Answer (score 27):

[In a previous answer, it was stated that the producers said that they felt that British/Irish accents "suited" the show](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133019/65294). I'm going to explain why they feel that way.

### Out-of-universe background on in-universe history

Although this question is not a duplicate thereof, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59533/65294) to [a related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59521/65294) pretty much sums it up: Although the books and the TV series are only related and are not equivalent (and they have been drifting further apart for quite some time), the author, George R. R. Martin, did take [heavy inspiration from the English Wars of the Roses](https://youtu.be/VjO55pKuBo4) (see [*Rolling Stone* interview](http://www.rollingstone.com/tv/news/george-r-r-martin-the-rolling-stone-interview-20140423)) — *Stark*←*York* and *Lannister*←*Lancaster* is just too obvious to ignore: The author isn't stupid and so he obviously meant that as a direct "hat-tip" to English history. Furthermore, in the same interview, he explains that one of the main the "boundaries" which define Westerosi "civilization" (and therefore by extension Westerosi "history" — since history is generally written by people with enough money/power to win wars and write about them) is inspired directly by [Hadrian's Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian%27s_Wall) (see [*The Journal* article](http://www.thejournal.co.uk/news/north-east-news/game-thrones-writer-inspired-hadrians-7214397)).

Now, although the TV series *Game of Thrones* is only *based* on GRRM's *A Song of Ice and Fire* and is not a direct television production thereof, this background story still stands in some form. What this means is that the show is firmly grounded in the genre of [Medieval fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_fantasy) (i.e. old-timey England plus magic and dragons!).

### Out-of-universe motivation: Sociolinguistics!

Now, just because the series is directly inspired by English/British history doesn't necessarily mean that the actors *have* to speak with modern British accents. However, [using British accents in (English) Medieval fantasy is a well-established tradition](http://dialectblog.com/2011/07/26/fantasy-british-accent/): Fantasy of this type typically draws heavily on contemporary views of Medieval European life (even J. R. R. Tolkien himself, [who is basically the father of mainstream fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_fantasy#Tolkien), [drew heavily from the history, mythology and linguistics of the British Isles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._R._Tolkien%27s_influences)) and framing these stories in a British accent gives us (especially people from the "New" World) a feeling of them being "old" — which fits because the author typically *wants* the reader to associate their world with Medieval times: If the actors all spoke in a "Wild West" accent from Texas in the 1800s, it would feel "weird" because it's an accent which is heavily associated with a completely different place and era. On the other hand, "Wild West"-style linguistic influences don't feel out of place in the [Firefly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_(TV_series)) universe at all because [it is very obviously inspired by Westerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_(TV_series)#Signature_show_elements) and lacks associations with "Old Europe" — which Medieval fantasy does have.

What this means is that modern British dialects/accents serve in fact as a "genrelect" associated with Medieval fantasy: They are a sort of [sociolect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolect) defining a character's connection to a particular genre. Just as it's weird to hear an old person use slang associated with younger speakers, it would be weird to hear a character in a Medieval fantasy universe speak, like, totally [like a Valley Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valleyspeak).

Moreover, the connotations associated with different English accents function just as well internally to the given fantasy universe as they do in our universe: The features of [Bronn](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Bronn)'s speech mark him as being from a class lower than [Tyrion](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Tyrion_Lannister), despite that Peter Dinklage is actually American and is just putting on a completely arbitrary pseudo-"South-eastern English aristocrat" English accent — Regardless of how "aware" the actor is of British sociolinguistic idiosyncrasies, he does know how to sound generically "posh" to viewers. If the actors just randomly used any accent (and actually, [they still *are* pretty random compared to actual geographic/social divisions in the UK](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2336568/HBOs-Game-Thrones-lambasted-mish-mash-British-accents.html)), we would lose the useful background information we get by hearing how they speak. Finally, the characters *themselves* have been proven to have the same sociolinguistic knowledge we do as viewers: Namely, when [Tywin Lannister corrects Arya's attempts at speaking like a commoner](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16722/65294), he states that a commoner would say *m'Lord* rather than *my Lord*. This mirrors sociolinguistic contrasts in real-life England both today and in the past: Using reduced forms such as *m'Lord* and usage of the *me*-possessive [*me Lord*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_personal_pronouns#Archaic_and_non-standard_forms) is associated with a lower-class background, whereas — on the flip side — using the non-reduced form *my Lord* is exclusive to educated classes: Someone from the upper crust may talk about *huntin' an' shootin'* when they feel like it, but the non-educated would *always* speak that way — hence why it was a [shibboleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth) which gave Arya away.

### TL;DR

The series is based on fantasy. Most people are used to hearing fantasy characters speak like the British, so anything else would be weird. Therefore, in order to let us recognize the characters' individual backgrounds/social class, the actors try to affect different English dialects which roughly correspond to equivalent backgrounds/classes in modern Britain.

Comment: Yes, Arabic high fantasy would probably be better served with Arabic-accented English, but, as I tried to explain here, the series is grounded in (English) Medieval fantasy... hence British accents.

Comment: Fair enough; Done.

Comment: And +1 you get for it. :)

Comment: Cheers, mate. (or maybe "thanks, brah!"?)

Comment: This answer seems to keep getting upvoted now and again; Do people like this pop culture/science/language mashup that much and, if so, how might I go about finding more questions like this to answer? Some sort of "ask a linguist" blog?-- on SE, they're not *that* common...

Comment: Well the best you can do is see the questions tagged with [languages](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

Comment: Yeah, saw that, but those questions are sadly more about trivia than actually about "languages"...

Comment: If you like questions about Languages and their evolution over time, you are welcome to join us on [History Stack Exchange](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) ;)

Comment: Sounds fun but, alas, historical linguistics is not my forte ;)

Comment: Great answer. I can't find it now but I saw an article ages ago theorising that "honest" characters got more northern (or Scottish) accents and "scheming" characters got more southern accents (hence for example southern-born Davos sounding geordie) - and I think they compared it to a real life trend of UK-based call centres choosing northerly locations like Newcastle, Glasgow and Sheffield because customer testing found people thought the voices sounded more honest and so were less likely to feel fobbed off.